# How to return data on WebSocket when new database entry is made FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am trying to write a simple API that collects measurements, and then streams them live to clients over a websocket with FastAPI. There are plenty of tutorials on how to send messages when triggered by the websocket manager, but I'm having a hard time getting the database trigger to send the message. Below is what I have so far:

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from sql_app.database import engine, Session
from sql_app import models
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
import sql_app.schemas as schemas
from sql_app.database import Base, get_db
import datetime
import uvicorn


def create_tables():
    print("Creating Tables..")
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()



@app.post("/measurement/")
async def create_measurement(measurement: schemas.MeasurementCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    # new_measurement = schemas.MeasurementCreate(**measurement.dict(), session=db)
    new_measurement = models.Measurement(**measurement.dict())
    db.add(new_measurement)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_measurement)
    return new_measurement


@app.post("/create_device/")
async def create_device(device: schemas.DeviceCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    new_device = models.Device(device_key=device.device_key,
                               name=device.name,
                               hardware=device.hardware,
                               firmware=device.firmware,
                               software=device.software
                               )
    db.add(new_device)
    db.commit()
    return db.refresh(new_device)

@app.get("/measurement/")
async def get_measurements(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(models.Measurement).filter(
        models.Measurement.timestamp >= datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    ).all()




@app.websocket("/ws")
async def dashboard_data(websocket: WebSocket, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    await websocket.accept()
    await websocket.send_json(
        jsonable_encoder(
            db.query(models.Measurement).filter(
                models.Measurement.timestamp >= datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).all()))
    while True:
        try:
            data = await models.measurement_stream(Depends(get_db))
            await websocket.send_text(data)
        except WebSocketDisconnect:
            return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

Models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Float, DateTime, event
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from fastapi import Depends
from .database import Base, get_db
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
from sql_app.database import Session


class Measurement(Base):
    __tablename__ = "measurements"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    device_key = Column(String(length=40), ForeignKey("devices.device_key"))
    inside_temp = Column(Float)
    outside_temp = Column(Float)
    inside_humidity = Column(Float)
    outside_humidity = Column(Float)
    current_capacity = Column(Float)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=lambda: datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone('America/Los_Angeles')))

    device = relationship("Device", back_populates="measurements")

    def _as_dict(self):
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}


@event.listens_for(Measurement, "after_insert")
async def measurement_stream(db: Session):
    return "test" #db.query(Measurement).filter(Measurement.timestamp >= datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).all()



class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = "devices"
    device_key = Column(String(length=40), unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    hardware = Column(String)
    firmware = Column(String)
    software = Column(String)

    measurements = relationship("Measurement", back_populates="device")
```

If I execute this now it just returns "test" as quickly as the loop runs. How can I make the message only send when there is an update to the database? Note: I am not even sure if my event listener for the measurement ORM class is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer, although I'm not sure of what other consequences might be of what I'm doing here. But what I have seems to work with multiple clients.

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def dashboard_data(websocket: WebSocket, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    flag = asyncio.Event()
    @event.listens_for(models.Measurement, "after_insert")
    def measurement_stream(*args, **kwargs):
        flag.set()
        print("event set")
    await websocket.accept()
    await websocket.send_json(
        jsonable_encoder(
            db.query(models.Measurement).filter(
                models.Measurement.timestamp >= datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).all()))
    while True:
        try:
            await flag.wait()
            await websocket.send_json(jsonable_encoder(
            db.query(models.Measurement).filter(
                models.Measurement.timestamp >= datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).all()))
            flag.clear()
        except WebSocketDisconnect:
            return None
```

Essentially what I've done here is put the event listener in the websocket route, which when a new measurement is input into the database, the event is triggered and allows the loop to continue one iteration until the flag is cleared again and it must wait for the event listener to fire again to set the flag. Like I said, there may be other performance or stability reprocussions to this, so if anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Comment: What happens when your server application is idle with the ```flag.wait()``` function and the client application close the connection? It looks like the server app won't close the connection right away.